# Get Percentage from two integers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, int

I am almost half way there to getting the percentage of two integers i just need help with the final hurdle, here is my coding so far below it works but sometimes its like yes = 50 and no = 20% when it should be 50/50.

```
    int yes;
int no;
//Work out percentages
if ([VotedAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"No"]){
    yes = [currentYes intValue];
    no = [currentNo intValue] + 1;
}else{
    yes = [currentYes intValue] + 1;
    no = [currentNo intValue]; 
}


int total = yes + no + 1;
int pcntYes = (yes *100) / total;
int pcntNo = (no *100) / total;

float barNo = pcntNo / 100.0f;
float barYes = pcntYes / 100.0f;

//Set percent labels
yesPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", pcntYes];
noPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", pcntNo];
//Set Percent Bars

YesProgress.progress = barYes;
NoProgress.progress = barNo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be adding 1 to total. The total number of votes cast is simply yes + no.
Oh and don't forget to update currentYes and currentNo you haven't shown code that is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
 int yes = [cell.yesAnswer.text intValue] ;
 int no =  [cell.noAnswer.text intValue];
 int total = yes + no + 1;

 int pcntYes = (yes *100) / total;
 int pcntNo = (no *100) / total;

 float barNo = pcntNo / 100.0f;
 float barYes = pcntYes / 100.0f;

 cell. yesProcent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", pcntYes];
 cell. noProcent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", pcntNo];
```